# Disable scrolling when cursor is in div javascript?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I embed model 3D on my website, i want to temporarily disable scrolling only when cursor is inside of div with model 3D, because when i make zoom in or out model in this same time im moving on webpage.
Do you have any idea how to do it?

```html
<div class="3DBoxView" style="width: 80%; height: 465px;">
    <babylon>
        <model url="./External Source/Parts/GLB/<?php echo $partDetails['glb_file'];?>">
    </babylon>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events on your div to add/remove the CSS attribute `overflow: hidden` to/from the element you want to prevent scrolling.

Comment: How to disable scrolling temporarily? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily

Comment: @Jesse i though the same idea but you cant use that because the scroll will appear and disappear and it will looks strange and items will move in screen.

Comment: Then check out the link posted by hamboy75. Setting the overflow attribute is how most websites disable scrolling.